# How can i fix max form submit count to 3

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a question. I have a form page. If the username to be sent from the form matches the database 3 times a day, do not submit more forms. Briefly; each user can send data with the form 3 times a day. How can i do this?
You can review my source code below.

```
<?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['guncelle'])){                           

                        $kadi   =   $_POST["kadi"];
                        $gpa    =   $_POST["gpa"];
                        $miktar =   $_POST["price"];
                        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
                        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                            $ekstra = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM vw_veriler_gonderim_adetleri where tarih ='date('Y-m-d')' and kullanici = '$kadi'");
                            $dee = mysqli_fetch_row($ekstra);
                            $more = mysqli_query($db_connect,"select * from ekstrahak where kullaniciadi = '$kadi'");
                            $and = mysqli_fetch_row($more);
                            $tum = 3 + $and[4];

                            $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM veriler WHERE gpa ='$gpa'");
                            $karaliste = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM karaliste WHERE kullaniciadi ='$kadi'");
                            $sorgula = mysqli_num_rows($karaliste);
                            $degil = $result->fetch_row();
                            if ($dee[1] <= $tum){
                            if ($degil[0] == 0 && $sorgula < 1) {
                                $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO veriler SET kullanici='$kadi', gpa='$gpa', durumu=0, miktari='$miktar',tarih='$date'");
                                if ($query) {
                                    echo("<script>
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Gönderildi!',
                                    'Ödeme talebiniz alındı. 10 dakika içinde işleme alınacaktır.',
                                    'success'
                                  )
                                </script>");
                                }

                            } else {
                                echo("<script>
                            Swal.fire({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Hata!',
                                text: 'Girmiş olduğunuz kod daha önce kullanılmış veya Karalistedesiniz!',
                              })
                            </script>");
                            }
                        } else {
                                echo("<script>
                            Swal.fire({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Hata!',
                                text: 'Hakkınız doldu',
                              })
                            </script>");
                            }
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Set a flag/counter in your table and check if = 3

Comment: use a mysqli_num_rows and pull the count, if its 3 or more then ignore the form submission by outputting appropriate notification message https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php